# Angular2 Generic Async Validator in Reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a reactive form and a form control that must unique:

```js
this.form = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(this.initialValue, [
    Validators.required,
  ], this._uniqueNameValidator.bind(this)),
});
```

I've wrote an async validator that calls a method from my app service:

```js
private _uniqueNameValidator(control: FormControl) {
    const value = control.value.trim();
    if (value === '' || value === this.initialValue) {
      return of(null);
    }
    control.markAsTouched();
    return timer(500).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this._appService.validateName(value, this.selectedGroupId);
      }),
      map(response => {
        return response ? {nameTaken: true} : null;
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        return of(null);
      })
    );
 }
```

The service method is a simple http `GET` that returns a `boolean` value:

```
validateName(name: string, groupId: number): Observable<boolean> {
 // ...
 return this._http.get<boolean>(url);
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kedup

Now, in my app a have many another forms with controls that must be unique. The uniqueness is checked async, but in other services methods and in other routes.
I don't want to copy the code for the validator in every component that needs an async validator for uniqueness.

**The problem**:
I want to write a generic validator, that takes as parameters a service method that must be called in order to determine if the value is unique or not, and the initial form value.

I wrote the following function:

```js
export function UniqueAsyncValidator(fn: any, initialValue: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    const value = control.value.trim();
    if (value === '' || value === initialValue) {
      return of(null);
    }
    control.markAsTouched();
    return timer(500).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return fn(value);
      }),
      map(response => {
        return response ? {nameTaken: true} : null;
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  };
}
```

And form definition:

```
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(this.initialValue, [
        Validators.required,
        ], UniqueAsyncValidator(this._appService.validateName, this.initialValue).bind(this)),
   });
```

It seems that the service method is called, but the context (`this`) in the service method is undefined:

```
validateName(name: string, groupId: number): Observable<boolean> {
  // ....
  console.log( 'this: ', this );  // -> returns undefined 
  return this._http.get<boolean>(url);
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbbgc8

Thanks!

Comment: Second link is broken

Comment: i've fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not making the same function call in both versions. Your service function expects  `groupId`. You should call the service with this arg in your callback.

```js
const uniqueValidator = UniqueAsyncValidator(
  value => this._appService.validateName(value, this.selectedGroupId), 
  this.initialValue).bind(this);

this.form = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(this.initialValue, [
    Validators.required,
  ], uniqueValidator)
});
```

When you create the instance of `UniqueAsyncValidator`, you are passing in a callback. This allows you to reuse the logic inside the validator, and inject the function that will make the call.

```
value => this._appService.validateName(value, this.selectedGroupId)
```

This is arrow function syntax. It is simply declaring an anonymous function that accepts one parameter - `value` (this is being passed in by your validator) - and returns `this._appService.validateName(value, this.selectedGroupId)`.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynmzyu

Comment: thanks for your reply, it seems it works. but I don't really understand the `value => this._appService.validateName(value, this.selectedGroupId)`. Can you please explain it a little bit?

Comment: You will be creating an instance of `UniqueAsyncValidator` every time you want to use it. You could theoretically have a unique callback each time. If this is the case, then you just pass in that unique callback at the point of constructing it. This is the point of a callback?

Comment: I will add an explanation to my answer

Comment: I would recommend adding a type to `fn` - this makes it clear what you are dealing with. `fn: (value: string) => Observable<boolean>`. It's a function that accepts 1 string, and returns an observable boolean

Comment: And if you are always passing in an arrow function, you don't need `.bind()`, and you can just call `fn(value)` inside the validator. But what you have is fine, I'm just giving you options :)